# PYTHON rumps program stops responding after subprocess calls another script

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently working on a project that contains many system tray utilities on mac osx, one of these utilities is a 'fake friend soundboard' where I am to enable the user to click on the module then select as example "Discord Ping x1" and the program playback a soundfile of the ping.

Im using **RUMPS** which enables me to add menus to the system tray however when trying to use libraries to play sounds directly through upon the @rumps.clicked, nothing seems to happen

Instead I've programmed it to run another script that can easily play the sound inside another folder containing all the sounds.

When running the script and clicking a sound, it plays the sound exactly as intended,

but then the program **stops responding...**

Is this something I'm doing wrong with my code or is there another way i could play the sound using this library?

Heres the code:

```
import rumps
import subprocess

class sound(rumps.App):
    def __init__(self):
        super(sound, self).__init__("")
        self.menu = ["Fake friend soundboard",
                     None,
                     "Discord Sounds:",
                     "Ping x1",
                     "Incoming Call",
                     "Enter Call",
                     "Leave Call",
                     "Mute",
                     "Deafen",
                     None,
                     "Skype Sounds:",
                     "Incoming Call",
                     None,
                     "Random:",
                     "okbuddyretard",
                     None]

        @rumps.clicked("Ping x1")
        def about(sender):
            subprocess.run("python3 soundboard/discord_pingx1.py", shell=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sound().run()
```

In the soundboard folder there is the sounds folder containing the discord folder containing **
discord_ping.wav
The soundboard folder also hold the discordd_pingx1.py script which is below.

```
import pyglet

def sound():
    sound = pyglet.resource.media('sounds/discord/discord_ping.wav', streaming=False)
    sound.play()
    pyglet.app.run()

sound()
```

after running my main.py (opens all the modules)
and clicking the sound tab and then clicking the button set to make the sound,
it plays, but then stops responding.

Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend avoiding the insert of `subprocess` or sys-calls inside of a Python script that executes Objective-C code. This leads to Aborts and Traps. Instead, refer to Apple's APIs and utilize AppleScript (osascript).

Here is a better implementation that calls a script to call your script from osascript:

**exec.py**

```py
import platform
import subprocess, sys, os

applescript = '''\
  do shell script "bash /path/to/file/myShellScript.sh"\
'''

# parse and stdout
args = [item for x in [("-e",l.strip()) for l in applescript.split('\n') if l.strip() != ''] for item in x]
proc = subprocess.Popen(["osascript"] + args ,stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
progname = proc.stdout.read().strip()
sys.stdout.write(str(progname))
```

The parser takes the string with the osascript in it and parses it for a stdout write. Stdout writes are very safe, considering they are handling data from the same thread.

**/path/to/file/myShellScript.sh** (add the shebang on line 1 as well)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

python3 soundboard/discord_pingx1.py
```

This 100% handles your problem without causing subprocess errors. If you get hung with subprocess, your computer will continue running Python3. If the Application doesn't stop freezing, exit the app by `cmd`+`Space` and typing Activity Monitor. Then, find Python3 by `cmd`+`f` and typing python3. Click it and press `Quit` in the top left corner (the X or stop-light symbol).